# My Windows 10 virtual machine won't recognize USB memory drive anymore

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-10, usb-drive

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with Oracle VM VirtualBox v6.1.40. It has Windows 10 virtual machine installed. A little over month ago it stopped working, but I managed to fix the problem after switching USB controller option from 3.0 to 1.1 like [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051161/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005) suggested.

However, after that the Windows 10 was unable to recognize my 8.0 GB Kingston DT 100 G2 (PMAP) USB memory stick. I tried to switch the USB controller to 2.0, but then it was unable to start again like with 3.0. I tried to update the VirtualBox to 7.0 version but then the Windows 10 wouldn't work even with 1.1 controller.

My USB mouse and keyboard, however, work just fine in Windows 10. Also the VirtualBox itself seems to recognize the Kingston stick, as my Ubuntu won't get a notification if I install the stick while Windows 10 is on.

I have 3 options, at least one I wish to make work:

1. Make the Windows 10 work with USB 3.0 controller
2. Make the Kingston memory stick work in Windows 10, even with 1.1 controller
3. Get some other memory stick that'll work with 1.1 controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an update prompt for extension pack and now the virtual machine starts with 3.0 controller setting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1263842)

Comment: But I am the author.