# virtualbox: How do I fix NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04

I am trying to start a windows oracle virtual box, but while the VM powers up, I get this error:

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}
```

I tried this, but it didn't change anything: [virtualbox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051161/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005#answer-1131716) There was nothing found and therefore I completed all 3 steps.

I am unsure how to debug this further an appreciate any help.

## Additional info

### Main Board

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: 198F
    Version: KBC Version 15.59
    Serial Number: PDXVC001X6NEGW
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:  
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Unknown
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

### BIOS

```
BIOS Information
        Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
        Version: L71 Ver. 01.39
        Release Date: 09/26/2016
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 8 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                Smart battery is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Function key-initiated network boot is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 1.39
        Firmware Revision: 21.89
```

### System Information

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP EliteBook 840 G1
    Version: A3009DD10303
    Serial Number: CNU421B1DS
    UUID: 2b64bbff-8540-11e3-b4b3-c316d107e0ff
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: G9T17EP#ABU
    Family: 103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=ELI
```

Comment: The first line indicates you need to enable VT-x in your BIOS. If you post the model of your computer or motherboard we can find the exact setting you need to enable from the manual

Comment: I added the info. Does this help?

Comment: I can't see the right detail in there, I just need the model of your laptop or computer

Comment: I added System Information and I think this includes what you need to identify the BIOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable CPU Virtualisation (VT-x) which is what allows Virtual Box to assign cores of your CPU to virtual machines.
I've got the below info from the guide for your laptop [here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04655205.pdf).

1. Turn off your laptop
2. Turn it back on and when it says `Press the ESC key for Startup Menu` press ESC.
3. Press F10 to enter the BIOS

(The following steps are from a [generic HP Bios Guide](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_3900499-3190557-16) that I think is still relevant but might not be perfect.)

4. Use the `Arrow Keys` to  to System Configuration
   [image]
5. Locate the option for `Virtualization Technology` and enable it.
6. Press F10 to save and exit.

Comment: Thank you. There were two settings in "Device Settings" one to enable it in general and one to enable "direct I/O" I enabled both and it seems to work now.

Comment: Glad that worked 